# How to manage multiple data syncing threads

Tags: java, android

I have two threads, each of which handle syncing data one way either from the server or to the server. The thread for getting data off the server needs to run once a day. The other sending data to the server needs to run every 15 mins. I am currently using an Alarm Manager to create repeating alarms for each of these threads. This is then received by a BroadcastReceiver, from  which i call an activity, which then according to the data passed into the activity either runs the to server syncing thread or the from server syncing thread. I am using the activity to display a dialog box, to prevent the user from using the application until the syncing has been completed as they both access the database required by the application. Is this the correct way to accomplish this task, or are there better alternatives?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can put a fullscrenn Interstitial Ad, during the Syncing. That's about all I can give you as an advice, because anyway the answer can be in contradiction with your design overall. When you ask such a thing, you must also provide the model, under which your application works, in order to receive the corresponding advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not really fit for SO... This is more a debate without any details on how your app works.

Anyway I would use an Android Service to do so. You do not need to bother the user just to upload data. Also why block the use of the app for uploading? Since for uploading you only need to read, just make a snapshot of the current data and upload it. Any changes the user is making right now will be uploaded in next upload, so that's not a problem.

For downloading, you most likely do need to block the app use, but maybe not. This depends on how the app works. You could start DB transactions to avoid doing that.

Comment: For uploading the data, i guess it is not necessary to block, but i thought for the downloading, a user may be entering data into the database, which could stop the updating. Not sure though

Comment: Again: DB transactions ;) Check that out.